# how to get JS alert when any web pages is shared in google plus or any social media, in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, alert

I am trying to show an alert when any of my web pages is shared in social medias like google plus, twitter, facebook and so on. Since i have a very little knowledge in JS i want some help here. This is the code i got from google plus for sharing the page.

```
    <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer>
    </script>

   <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
      <div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>
```

I want to add alert showing message something like "page is being shared". How can I do that. Any kin of help is appreciated. Thank you

See my **EDIT**

```
          <html>
           <head>
                <title>Your Website Title</title
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/css/bootstrapValidator.min.css"/>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.bootstrapvalidator/0.5.3/js/bootstrapValidator.min.js"> </script>
     </head>
     <body>
                     <script>
               buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action]');
          for ($i=0, len = buttons.length; $i < len; $i++) {
              buttons[$i].addEventListener("click", function() {
                  alert("Thank you for sharing!");
              }
          }
          >
          </script>


          <!-- Place this tag in your head or just before your close body tag. -->
          <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>

          <!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
          <div class="g-plus" data-action="share" data-height="15"></div>
      </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could put an event listener on the buttons to popup an alert when a user clicks the button.

```
// makes a nodelist of all buttons with the `data-action` attribute
buttons = document.querySelectorAll('[data-action]'); 

//iterates through the nodelist and adds the click function to each
for ($i=0, len = buttons.length; $i < len; $i++) {
    buttons[$i].addEventListener("click", function() {
        alert("Thank you for sharing!");
    }
}
```

Comment: I put this tag on my HTML body part but it didn't work. Simply the content is shared without alert. How can i do that?

Comment: You have an extra `>` at the bottom of the script. 
Use the inspector in your browser to read the console. It is very helpful for debugging errors.